# ConversationHandler в python_telegram_bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, бот

Столкнулся с проблемой - код не идет дальше и останавливается.

Это часть кода, отвечающего за `ConversationHandler` :

```
CHECK, CHECK_STORIES = range(2)
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start_callback)],
        states={
            CHECK: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & (~Filters.regex('^Отмена$')), check)],
            CHECK_STORIES: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & (~Filters.regex('^Отмена$')), check_stories)],
        },
        fallbacks=[MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^Отмена$'), check)],
    )
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
```

Проблема находится здесь:

```
def start_callback(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                                 text='какой-то текст')
    tm.sleep(3)
    return CHECK #здесь он останавливается, хотя должен перейти на функциюcheck


def check(update, context):
```